# Como unir duas variáveis array em um só em php?

Tags: php

Boa tarde

Tenho o seguinte código

```
<?php
include_once("con.php");

$pdo = conectar();

$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($data);

$idempresa = $data->idempresa;
$subcategoria = "Recebimento";

$buscaContaEntrada=$pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM conta WHERE empresa_idempresa=:idempresa AND subcategoria=:subcategoria');
$buscaContaEntrada->bindValue('idempresa', $idempresa);
$buscaContaEntrada->bindValue('subcategoria', $subcategoria);
$buscaContaEntrada->execute();

while ($linha=$buscaContaEntrada->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $return[] = array(
        'idconta'   => $linha['idconta'],
        'conta' => utf8_encode($linha['conta']),
        'idsubcategoria'    => utf8_encode($linha['subcategoria_idsubcategoria']),
    );
}

echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

Mas preciso pegar o dado idsubcategoria, fazer outro select, no banco de dados, e o resultado, jogar dentro do $return... Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Deixe eu tentar entender: você quer pegar o valor da chave `idsubcategoria` e fazer uma consulta `sql` com esse valor ?

Comment: Não, isso eu já faço...@MagicHat. O que quero fazer é unir esse $return[] a outro que vou montar.

Comment: Teria como adicionar como está a saria (var_dump) e como deseja que seja? Acho que isso iria ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, tira esse primeiro colchete

```
$return[] = array(
```

Vira

```
$return = array(
```

Porque dessa forma tu tá criando 2 níveis de array (return[0][dados]) e quando vai ler no js está dando object porque na verdade é object mesmo.

Para unir simplesmente dois arrays é array_merge, mas minha resposta aí resolve o que tu quer

Answer (score 1):

Para unir 2 `arrays` em 1 você pode usar a função [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-merge.php), exemplo :

```
<?php
$array1 = array("cor" => "vermelho", 2, 4);
$array2 = array("a", "b", "cor" => "verde", "forma" => "trapezoide", 4);
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
echo json_encode($result);
?>
//saida
{"cor":"verde","0":2,"1":4,"2":"a","3":"b","forma":"trapezoide","4":4}
```

Comment: Cara, na verdade é pra ser um object array, json.
Já usei array_merge, mas não ficou legal.
As posições [0], [1]... deve ser com nomes, entende?

Comment: Bom se eu entendi bem agora, veja a edição...

Comment: Entendeu o que precisi @MagicHat?

Comment: ah fiz uma edição, veja a saída, como é a saída que vc gostaria ?

Answer (score 0):

Cria uma função que busque os dados pelo IdCategoria e então adiciona o retorno dela no seu array.

```
while ($linha=$buscaContaEntrada->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $novaVariavelParaInserirNoArray = buscarInformacoesNoBanco($linha['subcategoria_idsubcategoria']);//funcao que realiza sua busca.
    $return[] = array(
        'idconta'   => $linha['idconta'],
        'conta' => utf8_encode($linha['conta']),
        'idsubcategoria'    => utf8_encode($linha['subcategoria_idsubcategoria']),
        'informacoesTrazidasDoBanco' => $novaVariavelParaInserirNoArray
    );
}
```

Acredito que isso deva bastar.

Comment: No console aparece um array com 2 objetos dentro. [Object, Object].
usei o comando array_merge do php, mas não ficou legal

Comment: Mas como adicione o retorno no array?

Comment: você pode tratar o retorno do fetch que a função "buscarInformacoesNoBanco" traz, dessa forma fazendo com que seja retornado ou um array ou um valor. Caso seja um array basta usar a função [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) com o resultado da função "buscarInformacoesNoBanco" e o seu $return.
Se por outro lado o retorno dessa busca que você realiza utilizando o "subcategoria_idsubcategoria" for um valor, você pode utilizar a função  [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php).